# Can't import large file PHP excel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcelreader

I'm trying to upload 10k+ data in my database (using PHP and Mysql). However the file seems to be too large. If I reduce the size of the file to about 9300 records it works just fine but above that my code seems to fail at the following line `$excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);` 
I'm including only a snippet of my code (where I think is relevent to this question). I have the `upload_max_filesize=124M` and `post_max_size=124` as well. What could be the problem?

```
<?php
        $tmpfname = $_FILES['file_save']['tmp_name'];
    echo "0";   
        $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
echo "1";
        $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
        echo "2";
        $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
        echo "3";
        $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();

    ?>
```

Comment: Question is what error you get. Take a look into your http servers error log file. Most likely you run out of memory. Or maybe out of the configured time limit.

Comment: @arkascha Sorry if I come off ignorant but where is my error log file located?

Comment: I hope below link using for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869743/how-to-import-large-excel-file-to-mysql-database-using-php Thank you

Comment: Not ignorant at all! A bit lazy maybe ;-) That is documented and also answered here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel

Comment: @RaguNatarajan sorry but looked at that already and didn't solve it. Thank you

Comment: @arkascha assuming I'm running out of memory, how can I solve this issue? thanks

Comment: Well, 1. by raising the memory limit configured for the execution of requests, 2. by reducing the amount of memory actually used. The later often is the much more intelligent approach. Potential gains you can try to find especially include parts where things are processed without freeing memory in between, so sections of code that do not scale. Data processing loops are typical candidates for that.

Answer (score 0):

follow this link : http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/usage/

1. Download and unzip [*bigdump.zip*](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump.zip) on your PC.
2. Open *bigdump.php* in a text editor, adjust the database configuration and dump file encoding.
3. Drop the old tables on the target database if your dump doesn’t contain “DROP TABLE” (use phpMyAdmin).
4. Create the working directory (e.g. *dump*) on your web server
5. Upload *bigdump.php* and the dump files (*.sql or *.gz) via FTP to the working directory (take care of **TEXT** mode upload for *bigdump.php* and *dump.sql* but **BINARY** mode for *dump.gz* if uploading from MS Windows).
6. Run the *bigdump.php* from your web browser via URL like *http://www.yourdomain.com/dump/bigdump.php*.
7. Now you can select the file to be imported from the listing of your working directory. Click “Start import” to start.
8. BigDump will start every next import session automatically if JavaScript is enabled in your browser.
9. Relax and wait for the script to finish. Do NOT close the browser window!
10. **IMPORTANT:** Remove *bigdump.php* and your dump files from your web server.

Comment: Whilst this is probably possible the question is: _why_? Why not simply fix the issue at hand and upload and process the image? Why should one want to additionally install, configured and use an insecure FTP server? Why rely on some arbitrary external solution for something as simple as a file upload?